# Passing in the dtypes for many columns at once when creating a dataframe through csvs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large file with many columns (think 50+) and need to pass in the dtypes for all of them as strings to avoid mixed types. How can I do this efficiently without having to specify the column names for all 50+ columns?

Comment: So you have the dtypes already? Why not just load the column names and `zip` them?

Comment: @gmds the dtypes are all strings. And I'm sorry, I don't understand the rest of the comment? What do you mean by load the column names and zip them?

Comment: Never mind, I misunderstood your question. Try `pd.read_csv(path, dtype=str)`?